# MS Access VBA linking data and updating records from excel

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

What is the best approach to updating records that are saved in an excel file. For instance I have a MS Access database with a table in it that has `Product ID`, `ProductName`, and `ProductAge`.

I have this same table stored in an excel spreadsheet. I want to write a VBA code that will look into that excel spreadsheet and update my database table.

Comment: So far I have tried exporting the table as excel spreadsheet. I do not know the VBA code to link to that spreadsheet and update based on its values.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the records from the database and then import the spreadsheet data again using the below code.(Assuming its the same table)

```
Docmd.RunSql("delete from tblData")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tblData","C:\Data\Test.xls", True, "A1:E100"
```

Comment: I will give this code a try. In the meantime I need to us date the data into the ms access table.  For instance.  If some one adds a 4th record in the excel spreadsheet.  I need the VBA to search the database and ensure a duplicate 4th record doesn't already exists.

Comment: @rynwtts You should update (edit) your question to include that additional requirement. Don't force people to piece together the entirety of your question from tid-bits you've added in various comments.